# How to upload file in PHP5 and save file name on database (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, php-5.6

newbie here with PHP and trying to learn. I have a php codes that doesnt seem to be working... at least some part of it.

I wanted to store the file name on the database and store the file on a folder.
These are some parts of the codes that I have been working on...

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <img src="images/<?php if(file_exists('images/avatar/'.$session->userinfo['avatar'])){ echo 'avatar/'.$session->userinfo['avatar']; }else{ echo 'avatar1.png';}?>" class="img-circle" width="150">
    <input type="file" name="avatar" class="form-control"/>

    <label class="sr-only">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="50" value="<?php if($form->value("email") == ""){ echo $session->userinfo['email']; }else{ echo $form->value("email"); }?>" class="form-control"  placeholder="Email Address">

    <label class="sr-only">Current Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="curpass" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo $form->value("curpass"); ?>"  class="form-control custom-middle"  placeholder="Current Password">

    <label class="sr-only">New Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="newpass" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo $form->value("newpass"); ?>" class="form-control"  placeholder="New Password">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="bio" rows="5" maxlength="250" placeholder="Bio" style="resize: none;"><?php if($form->value("bio") == ""){ echo $session->userinfo['bio']; }else{ echo $form->value("bio"); }?></textarea>
  </div>

  <input type="hidden" name="subedit" value="1">
  <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Save Changes">

</form>
```

**DATABASE.PHP** *(where the updateUserField() function is from)*

```
function updateUserField($username, $field, $value){
  $q = "UPDATE ".TBL_USERS." SET ".$field." = '$value' WHERE username = '$username'";
  return mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
}
```

**PROCESS.PHP**

```
function procEditAccount(){
  global $session, $form;
  /* Account edit attempt */
  $retval = $session->editAccount($_POST['curpass'], $_POST['newpass'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['bio'], $_POST['avatar']);

  /* Account edit successful */
  if($retval){
     $_SESSION['useredit'] = true;
     header("Location: ".$session->referrer);
  }
  /* Error found with form */
  else{
     $_SESSION['value_array'] = $_POST;
     $_SESSION['error_array'] = $form->getErrorArray();
     header("Location: ".$session->referrer);
  }
```

}

**SESSION.PHP** *(where the *editAccount()* function is from)*

```
function editAccount($subcurpass, $subnewpass, $subemail, $subbio, $subavatar){
  global $database, $form;  //The database and form object


//working codes.....
//then below is the problem....


/* Change Avatar */
  if($subavatar){
    $subavatar = $_POST['avatar'];
    $folder = "../images/avatar/";

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"], $folder . $_FILES["avatar"]["name"]);
    $database->updateUserField($this->username,"avatar",$subavatar);
  }
}
```

You might be wondering why i used `$subavatar = $_POST['avatar'];` instead of `$_FILES["avatar"]["name"];` this is because, it wont save the name of the file on the database which i need. However, this only stores the name on the database but doesnt save the file on the folder.

Can someone help me figure it out, and tell mne what am I doing wrong and how to fix it. Please and thank you.

Comment: Apart from your problem, you seem to be wide open to sql injection.

Comment: hello, mind telling me why and what would be the best solution for this?

Comment: Stop using 10 year old database functions like `mysql_query`. They are unmaintained and insecure. Start over again with PDO.

Comment: it look's like `move_uploaded_file` is failing (already returning `FALSE`?) - it could have different reasons, maybe the destination (folder) is not writable by the webserver